# Casting between class objects in java

Tags: java, casting, floating-point, double

I have two classes `Float2` && `Double2`

```
public final class Float2 {
  public float width;
  public float height;
    
  public Float2 multiplyBy(float number) {
    return new Float2(this.width * number, this.height * number);
  }
}
```

```
public class Double2 {
  public double width;
  public double height;
}
```

I want to cast the result of multiplyBy method to a Double2 so that in the end I do not have `Float2 newRectangleSize = rectangleSize.multiplyBy(3.2f);` but `Double2 newRectangleSize` as the result of multiplication. Of course I can cast width and height values separately but I was wondering if there was a more ellegant solution in java?

Comment: `Double2 newRectangleSize = (Double2) rectangleSize.multiplyBy(3.2f);` would work if `Float2` could be cast to `Double2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `Double2` and `Float2` would be related types then casting could be possible.

As long as they aren't, you cannot cast them regardless the names of parameters are same including their types. However, you can use this advantage for a framework based on reflection that makes mapping between types easy, such as [MapStruct](https://mapstruct.org/):

```
@Mapper
public interface Double2Mapper {
 
    Double2Mapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(Double2Mapper.class); 

    @Mapping
    Double2 floatToDouble(Float2 float2); 
}
```

```
Double2 double2 = Double2Mapper.INSTANCE.floatToDouble(rectangleSize.multiplyBy(3.2f));
```

If you are not keen to use a framework (in case of only few specific and simple cases), I offer you two basic ways based on the pure OOP:

1. A constructor of `Double2` using `Float2` (assuming the fields remain `public`):

   ```
   public Double2(Float2 float2) {
       this.width = float2.width;
       this.height = float2.height;
   }
   ```
2. A method returning such type in the class `Float2`:

   ```
   public Double2 asDouble2() {
       return new Double2(this.width, this.height);
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

So clearly trying to cast in this case will result in a `ClassCastException`. One option would be to support an interface that is implemented by both classes that allows width() and height() to be defined as Number objects or even a type that extends Number. Then you could handle conversion on a implementation by implementation basis to handle precision loss in cases like int or short.

```java
interface Size<T extends Number> {

    T width();

    T height();

}
```

Another option might be to provide static factory methods to these classes to allow for the conversion of Double2 to Float2 and vice versa. It might look like this;

```java
public class Double2 {
    
    private final double width;

    private final double height;

    public Double2(double width, double height) {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }

    public static Double2 valueOf(Float2 float) {
        return new Double2((double) float.width, (double) float.height);
    }

}
```

```java
Float2 float2 = new Float2(2f, 2f).multiplyBy(2f);

Double2 double2 = Double2.valueOf(float2);
```